# Django form data with Azure Logic Apps

Tags: django, azure, azure-logic-apps

I got a Django form data which I need to post to Azure Logic App. When I post the data I get this error:

```
{"error":{"code":"NoResponse","message":"The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id '08585915990752009043423379830CU49'."}}
```

When I check Azure logs I see this error:

```
BadRequest. The property 'content' must be of type JSON in the 'ParseJson' action inputs, but was of type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.
```

So as I understand I need to change this data to JSON as it's sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
So my question is how can I do that? I'm new to Django so any help would be great.

My code looks like this:

Views.py

```
def home(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    vardas = request.POST.get('vardas')
    ToDate = request.POST.get('ToDate')
    FromDate = request.POST.get('FromDate')
    Pastabos = request.POST.get('Pastabos')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    Login_form.objects.create(vardas=vardas,ToDate=ToDate,FromDate=FromDate,Pastabos=Pastabos,username=username)
 
  
  return render(request, 'loginas/home.html', context)
```

My form in home.html

```
{% extends "loginas/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Login Testas</h1>
  <p class="d-flex justify-content-center">Dominari Prisijungimas</p>
 
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   
    <form action="http://link_to_azure" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Vartotojas</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="vardas" type="text" value="{{user.name}}"readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" value="{{user.email}}"hidden>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nuo</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="FromDate" type="date">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Iki</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="ToDate" type="date">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Prašymo priežastis</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="Pastabos" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary mr-2" type="submit" value="Pateikti" />
      
    </form>
    
     {% else %}<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="{% url 'signin' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-large ">Prisijungti</a>
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% endblock %}
```